# Can't get value of $POST

Tags: php, ajax, file

hello guys i have this problem i can't compare this two strings

```
<?php
 $dir = '/var/www/devData/test';

 // create new directory with 777 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
  mkdir ($dir, 0777);
 }



         $flag = 0;
         $stringData = $_POST['data']; // echo = null
         $file = "/var/www/devData/test/ciao.txt"; 
         $fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");

         while(!feof($fh)) {
                    $theData = fgets($fh, filesize($file));
                    array_push($arr,$theData);
                    $i++;
         }  
         for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++) 
         if($stringData == $arr[j]){ // is the problem 
            $flag = 1;
         }
         if($flag = 0){
            fwrite($fh, $stringData); // fwrite works perfectly even if i try to print $string the result is null 
         }
         fclose($fh); 



 ?>
```

Someone can explain me how can resolve the problem? The goal of this script is avoid the user to write two times the same things

Comment: So we're supposed to guess why `$_POST['data']` is undefined? My guess: *Something*'s wrong with your form.

Comment: not because i can write the contents of the $_POST into the file that is stange

Comment: I see this is tagged with `ajax` are you passing the data as post? What kind of ajax request are you making? Are you using a library such as jQuery.. so many questions!!

Comment: `$stringData = $_POST['data']; // echo = null` implies that the data was never there in the first place. So the question is: Where should it come from?

Comment: is there any input field with name data in your form?

Comment: that is the jquery function that send the data :  $.post("JS/foo.php", {data: options_label}, function(result){alert(options_label) }, "json");

Comment: i don't use form i just use one function that with jquery send the 'data' to the php file. i post the function above ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
     if($stringData == $arr[j]){ // is the problem 
                           ^^^
                      is missing a $
```

Activate error reporting and this should have been pointed out to you automatically:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: deceze thanks but even with $j is like every time the $flag = 1, so every time the comparsion of the two strings is every time true. and is not possible

Comment: Then do some more step-by-step debugging. Print the different variables at each step to figure out their values and why they have the values they do.

Comment: alrady done was strange that i printed the value of the write and have to be 1 but was 0, so i checked the file and the data was stored correctly. looks like if try to print the value before that the data is send. Really i don't know are two days that i have this kind of problem

Comment: Maybe simplify your code by using built-in functions: file() to read lines of a file into an array, in_array() to search the array for $stringData.